# Stuck with lifetimes: How to write a wrapper struct around a shared library?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm trying to write a wrapper struct around a shared libary in Rust:

```rust
pub struct LibraryWrapper<'lib> {
    lib: libloading::Library,
    func: libloading::Symbol<'lib, unsafe extern fn() -> u32>
}

impl<'lib> LibraryWrapper<'lib> { // lifetime `'lib` defined here
    pub fn new() -> libloading::Result<Self> {
        let lib: libloading::Library = libloading::Library::new(LIB_PATH)?;
        let func: libloading::Symbol<'lib, unsafe extern fn() -> u32> = unsafe { // type annotation requires that `lib` is borrowed for `'lib`
            lib.get(FUNC_NAME)? // borrowed value does not live long enough
        };

        Ok(Self {
            lib, func // `lib` dropped here while still borrowed
        })
    }
}
```

How do I tell the Rust compiler that `func` will not outlive `lib` because they're in the same struct? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the `lazy_static` crate. I think it's more convenient than `std::sync::Once` for my use case. Thanks @LinearZoetrope for bringing me to this idea!

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done because you cannot ensure that later some code won't destructure LibraryWrapper to keep func and drop lib. For example:

```rust
fn this_is_bad<'lib>(wrapper: LibraryWrapper<'lib>) -> libloading::Symbol<'lib, unsafe extern fn() -> u32> {
    let LibraryWrapper { lib, func } = wrapper;
    func
}
```

To manage something like that I'd suggest using an RC or ARC if you need it to be Send.

Comment: That makes sense. How do I need to change my code in order to use `Rc`? Simply wrapping the library in an `Rc` and calling `.clone()` doesn't help...

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, the borrow checked needs to ensure you don't destructure something to keep the func and drop the lib. I've wrestled with the several times and came to the following conclusion:

Dynamically linked `libloading` stuff is one of the few things where I think it's acceptable to turn into a `static`. If it's a hardcoded so/dll/dylib I generally make a special static with [`Once`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Once.html) for it so it takes legitimate effort to drop it. For unknown-at-compile-time loaded ones (e.g. managed via a config file) I generally Mutex-protect a `static` central registry that's just a `HashMap` with a key for the library name or path, and only allow the libraries to drop when the whole program terminates. Yes, this is basically a singleton, no I don't generally recommend doing this for almost anything else, this case is a special exception.

For added safety, I do recommend you isolate the static and only use functions or structs to refer to it, especially with the Hash Map registry because it's easy for someone to do a `remove` on it or overwrite the HashMap, or replace a lib with the same name carelessly. Since it's static, it still allows you to store the functions as another static/singleton as well without having to query the library for them every time if you really want (but I'm not sure there's even much performance overhead just requesting it every time, haven't benchmarked it).

I do this for a few reasons:

1. You typically want to use the functions as if they're a normal library, no different from linking FFI or statically pulling in another library. You have to know the function names anyway, so it's in effect the same as just having a file with those functions normally.
2. You don't have to pollute everything you want to reference the functionality in with a `'lib` lifetime or library function argument or additional member when other than the fact the library you're linking is *technically* dynamic it's just referencing a dependency. Your program ends up agnostic if it becomes, e.g., a statically linked library later (just delete the setup lines in the file wrapping the `static` dynamic library and change them to functions that point elsewhere).
3. You generally only need to/want to/should link a given dynamic library once in the whole program, which is pretty much what `static` is for if nothing else.
4. It's rare you want to get rid of a library, dynamic or not, until the program terminates.
5. It isolates the `unsafe` initialization and function loading code to one file (though a wrapper struct admittedly takes care of this too).

The most common exception to these reasons I'd see someone having is option 4, like if you have a highly configurable plugin system where the extra memory taken up by the plugins may legitimately matter if the user wants to disable old ones and activate new ones, and in that case devising a wrapper scheme may be the right call, or alternatively adding an `unsafe fn close_dynamic_lib_no_seriously_do_you_really_want_to_do_this(self)` in your library wrapper.

The only other exception I can think of is if you're writing something like a library for `crates.io` where you *really* want the user to be able to manage their dynamic libraries and supply them to your library for you (e.g. it may be in a non-standard path or they can choose between several implementations), and even then it's still probably beneficial to modify this way of doing it.

Comment: I think using a `HashMap` registry is overkill in my case because I'm only loading a single function from a single library. The `Once` thingy though fits very well in my opinion. Thanks!